# How to use an object in a constructor of a different class?

Tags: java

I'm trying to use an object in a constructor, the object is my Date Class.
I'm not sure but think I'm supposed to use an interface.

```
public class Date {

private int day;
private int month;
private int year;

public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
    this.year = year;
    checkMonth(month);
    checkDay(day);
}

public void checkMonth(int monthIn)
{
    if(monthIn < 1 || monthIn > 12)
    {
        System.out.print("the month is invalid");
    }
    else
    {
        month = monthIn;
    }
}
public void checkDay(int dayIn)
{
    if(dayIn < 1 || dayIn > 31)
    {
        System.out.print("the day is invalid and has been set to 1");
        day = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        day = dayIn;
    }
}

public int getDay()
{
    return day;
}
public int getMonth()
{
    return month;
}
public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "birth date: " + getDay() + "/" + getMonth() + "/" + getYear();
}
}
```

and a Employee class (the public void add() at the end was just trial and error not real sure if it should be there)

```
public abstract class Employee {

private String fName;
private String lName;
private int rsiNumber;
private Date DOB;

public Employee(String fName, String lName, int rsiNumber, Date DOB)
{
    this.fName = fName;
    this.lName = lName;
    this.rsiNumber = rsiNumber;
    this.DOB = DOB;
}

public String getFName()
{
    return fName;
}
public String getLanme()
{
    return lName;
}
public int getRsiNumber()
{
    return rsiNumber;
}
public Date getDOB()
{
    return DOB;
}

public void setFName(String fNameIn)
{
    fName = fNameIn;
}
public void setLName(String lNameIn)
{
    lName = lNameIn;
}
public void setRsiNumber(int rsiNumIn)
{
    rsiNumber = rsiNumIn;
}
public void setDOB(Date DOBIn)
{
    DOB = DOBIn;
}

public String toString()
{
    return null;
}
public void add(Date x)
{
    DOB  = x;
}
}
```

Along with some other subclasses of Employee.
I'm trying to use the Date as an object in the constructor for Employee, but when I create my Test class I get an error saying the constructor has not been defined.

I have been sick from college for the last few day's and am not sure how to get this to work.

this is my Test

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String [] args)
{

    Employee employees[] ={
            new Salaried("Joe", "Bloggs", "R5457998", 6, 15, 1944, 800.00 ),
            new Hourly( "Kate", "Wyse", "S6657998", 10, 29, 1960, 16.75, 40 ),
            new Commission("Jim", "Slowe", "K5655998", 9, 8, 1954, 10000, .06 )};



}
}
```

Comment: Date is already a class in Java, make sure you are pointing to the right one. Also try not to hide native classes with your own custom classes, rename your class with some project specific prefix.

Comment: What does the exact error say? and what do the constructors for `Salaried`, `Hourly`, and `Comission` look like?

Comment: @ Sam I am The exact error is The constructor Salaried(String, String, String, int, int, int, double) is undefined 

@Aakash Goyal
Thanks for the tip, as regards the naming of the class, I was just following the instruction from my lecturer, I could rename it, but I don't think its the problem. how could I be sure I'm pointing to my class?

Comment: use the package names as well for your classes that might have conflicting names. also make sure your are not importing java.util.Date or java.sql.Date.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Hourly( "Kate", "Wyse", "S6657998", new Date(10, 29, 1960), 16.75, 40 ),
```

Comment: I was given the array to use the way it is, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Play with arguments to super constructor

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be solve if u use the composition. You should create a Date object in the main.

```
    {  Employee employees[] ={
        new Salaried("Joe", "Bloggs", "R5457998",new Date( 6, 15, 1944), 800.00 ),
        new Hourly( "Kate", "Wyse", "S6657998",,new Date (10, 29, 1960), 16.75, 40 ),
        new Commission("Jim", "Slowe", "K5655998",,new Date( 9, 8, 1954), 10000, .06 )};}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are the last two arguments for but to work with the existing constructors, you will have to do something like the following.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{

    Employee employees[] ={
        new Salaried("Joe", "Bloggs", "R5457998", new Date(6, 15, 1944)),
        new Hourly( "Kate", "Wyse", "S6657998", new Date(10, 29, 1960)),
        new Commission("Jim", "Slowe", "K5655998", new Date(9, 8, 1954))
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this inside the array of `Employee` declaration:  `new Salaried("Joe", "Bloggs", "R5457998", new Date(6, 15, 1944), 800.00)`

And your `Salaried` constructure should be:

```
public Salaried((String fName, String lName, int rsiNumber, Date DOB, float f){
    super(fname, lname, rsiNumber, dob);
    this.f=f;
}
```